# full page scrolling issue on touch device after autoscrolling set to false

Tags: fullpage.js

I've total four 4 sections and a footer.
Section one, two , three are normal sections.
On section four I need normal scrolling as its height is more than window height.
Below code works fine with keyboard scrolling and mouse scrolling.
But On mobile I've issue while scrolling upward.
Please open the link on a touch device too see the issue.
[Js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gbathyal/baeggLv4/1/embedded/)

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">One</div>
  <div class="section">Two</div>
  <div id="three" class="section">Three</div>
  <div id="four" class="section fp-normal-height fp-normal-scroll">
    <div style="height:1000px;">Four</div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer style="height:300px;">Site footer</footer>



$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    hybrid:true,
    fitToSection: false,
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
                var loadedSection = $(this);

                if(loadedSection.attr("id")   == "four") {
                    $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(false);
                }
                if(loadedSection.attr("id")   == "three") {
                    $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(true);
                }


            },
});
```

when we swipe upward from section 4 (as at this point Autoscrolling has been set to false)  the swipe takes user directly to first section.
I think  The reason Its happening because, when user swipes, the page gets scrolled to the top as normal scrolling has been triggered. If I do console log I can see autoscrolling is being set back  to true when it passes section 3 but still page scrolls till top as swipe has triggered the scrolling when auto  scrolling was false .

if you open below link on mobile you will see the issue above described. Works fine for keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Expect issues.

The `hybrid` option is not documented which means is might not work as expected in all possible scenarios.